# Move Down consecutive items in array toggles

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm implementing a pick list component and I have following layout

[image]

When I'm moving the consecutive items it is toggling between those two

My code is as below,

```
moveDown(){
    let tempItem =[]
    this.selectedItems.forEach((item,index)=>{
      if(item.selected && index!== (this.selectedItems.length-1)){
       tempItem.push(item);
       this.selectedItems[index]=this.selectedItems[index+1];
       item.selected=false
       this.selectedItems[index+1]=item
      }
    });
    tempItem.forEach((item)=>{
      console.log(item)
      this.selectedItems.find(item1=>item1.id===item.id).selected=true;
    });
  }
```

Full code is available in the following **[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iRjOsmfgRzfEtcSNJFCJ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're modifying the list as you iterate over it, a simple modification to avoid this is to loop backward on the list (kinda similar to the idea or removing items from a list while iterating over it).

Try this code :

```
moveDown() {
    let tempItem = []
    for (let index = this.selectedItems.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
        let item = this.selectedItems[index];
        if (item.selected && index !== (this.selectedItems.length - 1)) {
            tempItem.push(item);
            this.selectedItems[index] = this.selectedItems[index + 1];
            item.selected = false
            this.selectedItems[index + 1] = item
        }
    }
    tempItem.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(item)
        this.selectedItems.find(item1 => item1.id === item.id).selected = true;
    });
}
```